# How do I define the derivative of hardsigmoid function in python?

Tags: python, function, jupyter-notebook

def hard_sigmoid(x):
return np.maximum(0, np.minimum(1, (x /6)+ 1/ 2))

I am using the code above to define the hardsigmoid function but I would like to know how to implement its derivative

Answer (score 2):

```
def hardsigmoid(x: float) -> float:
  return np.maximum(0, np.minimum(1, (x /6)+ 1/ 2))

def hardsigmoid_d(x: float) -> float:
  return 0 if x >=3 or x<=-3 else 1/6
```

That should work